# Excel - Nasdaq Dividend History (Get External Data from Web)

Tags: excel, excel-external-data, vba

I would like to create a refreshable query for dividend history from Nasdaq's website, URL for Apple here (http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/aapl/dividend-history)

When I try to run Excel's native "New Web Query", the dividend history table does not appear to be a selectable option. What is the best way to extract this information into a spreadsheet?

If possible it would also be really helpful if the query can be run referencing a ticker that's in a certain cell.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Edit: I'm looking specifically for the dividends and their announcement dates and could only find this information consolidated on Nasdaq's website. If there is an alternative available that is more excel friendly that would also be helpful.

Comment: I could not find any that report the dividends and the announcement dates

Comment: I was unclear, I will update to be more specific

Comment: You could copy/paste then text to columns? But that would suck if you're doing this for 1000s

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm looking to avoid. Would prefer to not have to manually copy/paste for numerous companies and also repeat each quarter

Comment: So why are you doing this? If for school/work, they should have bloomberg or similar.

Comment: Unfortunately the programs we have can pull the ex/eff date, record date and payment date. Everything except the announcement date

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try - VBA web scraping is not the most elegant but all the tools are there to achieve the objective:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Call PasteNasdaqTickerTableHtmlToSheet(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4"), "aapl")
End Sub

Sub PasteNasdaqTickerTableHtmlToSheet(ByRef ws As Worksheet, ByVal strTicker As String)

    Dim strTableData As String
    Dim objDataObject As Object

    strTableData = GetTableHtmlFromUrl("http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/" & strTicker & "/dividend-history", "quotes_content_left_dividendhistoryGrid")

    Set objDataObject = CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")

    With objDataObject
        .SetText strTableData
        .PutInClipboard
    End With

    ws.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False

End Sub


Function GetTableHtmlFromUrl(ByVal strUrl As String, ByVal strTableId As String) As String

    Dim objHtmlReader As Object
    Dim strDocumentHtml As String
    Dim objHtmlParser As Object
    Dim objHtmlTables As Object
    Dim strTableHtml As String
    Dim intTableCounter As Integer

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    'get document html
    Set objHtmlReader = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With objHtmlReader
        .Open "GET", strUrl, False
        .Send
        strDocumentHtml = .ResponseText
    End With
    Set objHtmlReader = Nothing

    'return all html if no id supplied
    If strTableId = "" Then
        GetTableHtmlFromUrl = strDocumentHtml
        Exit Function
    End If

    'now parse html for tables
    Set objHtmlParser = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    objHtmlParser.body.innerHTML = strDocumentHtml
    Set objHtmlTables = objHtmlParser.getElementsByTagName("table")

    'iterate tables and check id against our input
    For intTableCounter = 1 To objHtmlTables.Length
        If objHtmlTables.Item(intTableCounter).getAttribute("id") = strTableId Then
            strTableHtml = objHtmlTables.Item(intTableCounter).outerHTML
            Exit For
        End If
    Next intTableCounter
    Set objHtmlTables = Nothing
    Set objHtmlParser = Nothing

    'return table html
    GetTableHtmlFromUrl = strTableHtml

    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Number & " : " & Err.Description
    Set objHtmlReader = Nothing
    GetTableHtmlFromUrl = ""

End Function
```

Comment: I feel it is a useful answer.